# WooCommerce - Custom User Registration Fields

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I was following this blog post https://www.themelocation.com/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-user-registration-form-in-woocommerce/ to learn about creating custom user fields in Woo (for registration).

The post above worked, and I was able to see new fields during registration, but I had two questions:

1. How can I get these fields to appear when I'm editing a user in wp-admin? I didn't notice them rendering on the edit user page.
2. Right now Woo (by default) lets you just register with an e-mail. I wanted to also use a first name and last name (my custom fields), but this is already a field on the users in WordPress, so I don't want to duplicate fields. Is there a way to somehow pull in/use/associate an existing field (such as name) during the Woo registration?

Thanks so much for any help/guidance you all can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 You can use this plugin for [display](https://wordpress.org/plugins/codepress-admin-columns/) your custom fields in the admin view.

2 In your template HTML file, find the `form`, and use the default `id` & `name` tag : "Firstname" / "Lastname" ...ext

Comment: Thanks Paul - could you elaborate on #2? Did you mean my Woo template that I'm overriding? I just enter "firstname" and "lastname" as fields and it'll map to WordPress default fields?

Comment: Yes absolutely. You have to overriding the woocommerce login template page. Find the form, then change the id="your-value" and the name="value" for each fields (firstname and lastname).

Comment: ok thanks. For the name fields, I just made an input with name and id of "firstname" and registered, but the first name field still isn't displaying anywhere in Woo or in the User page of wp-admin. What does the field name have to be specifically?

Comment: Just follow all the steps of this tutorial : https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-first-last-name-account-register-form/